# Select subarray and its length in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions

How can I get subquery array and it`s count?

```
SELECT location.country,    
       (SELECT array(
            SELECT competition.id
            FROM competition
            WHERE location.id = competition.location_id )) AS list,
       array_length(list, 1) AS list_count
FROM location
```

I am trying to get `competition list` for every `country`.
Query works fine without: `array_length(list, 1) AS list_count`

It is arguing that `column 'list' doesn't exists`.
Model: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c449

Comment: Can you add an example datamodel on sqlfiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15

Comment: Your question is unclear. You need to add a table definition and define the array.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry, I have edited question.

Comment: I don't see much of an improvement. Still no table definition. Still your query is incomplete and the question unclear. Also, the description doesn't match the code. `array_length(p,1)` does not even reference `list` ... I can only guess:  It's not possible to reference a column alias on the same query level. You would have to use a subquery.

Comment: @Wolph http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c449

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for help. You were right about same query level.

Comment: Now the question makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably even simpler / faster: aggregate *and count* in a separate query and join to it (thereby avoiding your original problem to begin with):

```
SELECT l.country, c.list, c.list_count
FROM   location l
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT location_id AS id
         ,array_agg(id) AS list
         ,count(*) AS list_count
   FROM   competition
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (id)
```

Should be faster as long as you fetch large parts of the table or all of it.

Comment: That makes more sense for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
select country, 
       list, 
       array_length(list, 1) as list_count
from (
  SELECT country,    
         (SELECT array(
            SELECT competition.id
            FROM competition
            WHERE location.id = competition.location_id )) AS list
  FROM location
) t
```

Using an aggregate *might* be faster though:

```
select country, 
       list, 
       array_length(list, 1) as list_count
from (
  SELECT l.country,    
         array_agg(c.id) as list
  FROM location l
    JOIN competition c ON l.id = c.location_id
  GROUP BY l.country
) t
```